# Run DockerCompose File in Background with the specific configuration(yaml) file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need `docker-compose` to run all the containers in the background.

I know, if i have one `docker-compose.yaml`. Then, it is go to the directory in which the configuration file is present and run:

`docker-compose up -d`

But, In my case, i have 3 `docker-compose.yaml` files in the configuration folder. And whenever, i run

`docker-compose -d docker-compose.yaml up`

It doesn't executes/ runs the container.

But, if i run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up`. Then, the docker containers will start executing on the foreground terminal.

I want these dockers to run detached from the terminal. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker has -d option for detached or you can use the usual & at the end of any linux command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

P.s: It is a good idea to give a name to your container (specially when using -d) using the `--name={some_name}` so that you can easily get back to that container later using the name

Comment: I tried with your command which is `-f -d`. It didn't work.

Comment: what error message did you get?, I also noticed, the -f has to be followed by the filename, so it's kind of normal it didn't work

Comment: try it now, I edited the command, don't have access to my usual pc that has docker but I think this should work now

Comment: Thanks it worked. I am not sure why, it had to be in the end. I tried so many permutations for placing that `-d` flag. Anyhow, It was of great help. Accepted your answer.

Comment: because " -d" is a flag for `run`,  not a flag for `docker-compose` command so it has to be after the run. the -f is the filename flag for docker-compose, so this one has to be after docker-compose, I'm pretty sure I saw this somewhere in the documentation of docker, but can't find the exact link now

Answer (score 0):

Run below to command to specify docker-compose.yml file including build and send in background;

**docker-compose -f docker-compose-1.yml up -d --build**

This will also build new image if there are any changes in the project else it will run the same container.